# Как форматировать код на StackOverflow, чтобы под ним появлялась кнопка "Выполнить код"?

Tags: stackoverflow

Собственно, есть такой вот [документ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Прочитал, понравилось. Чего-то не знал, теперь возьму на заметку. Вопрос же заключается в том, как именно форматировать приводимые куски кода, чтобы под вопросом или ответом появлялась кнопка "Выполнить код"?

Comment: вопрос для меты, при создании ответа для этого есть спец кнопка (над полем для ввода, справа)

Comment: ctrl + m  и туда рабочий код(css, html,js)